# Search for an element within another element using Python Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following element's xpath:

```
/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[6]/div/div/div/div[1]
```

Within that div, there is the following element:

```
/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[6]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/span
```

How can I search within the first element for the second element? Here's some code to illustrate what I mean (doesn't work, but the idea is there):

```
parent = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[6]/div/div/div/div[1]')
child = parent.find_element(By.XPATH, '/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/span')
```

I also have the class_name for the child element (_1RIl585IYPW6cmNXwgRz0J), so if what I'm asking for with xpath's isn't possible is there a way I could do it with a class name? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**How and Why I'm Doing This:**

Go to website: https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/usqr2/americans_of_reddit_would_you_vote_for_an_openly/

Find this comment:

[image]

(xpath = `/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[6]/div/div/div/div[1]`)

Then within that comment, find: `/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[6]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/span`, which contains text telling me if this a parent comment or child comment ('level 1' is parent, 'level 2' is child, 'level 3' is child of child, and so on). I want that data, since I need to know if the comment I'm looking at is a parent or child.

**HTML OF COMMENT** (I'm trying to access that 'level 1' data):

```html
<div><div><div><div id="t1_i964kf3" style="padding-left:16px" tabindex="-1" class="_3sf33-9rVAO_v4y0pIW_CH"><div class="_1DooEIX-1Nj5rweIc5cw_E"><div class="_3Wv3am0TXfTcugZJ6niui"><div class="_36AIN2ppxy_z-XSDxTvYj5 t1_i964kf3 undefined"><i class="threadline"></i></div></div></div><div class="Comment t1_i964kf3 P8SGAKMtRxNwlmLz1zdJu HZ-cv9q391bm8s7qT54B3 _1z5rdmX8TDr6mqwNv7A70U"><div class="TmlaIdEplCzZ0F1aRGYQh" role="presentation"></div><div class="_2CkgPEY8ljDZH3np9UY1ws">
                <img alt="" src="https://www.redditstatic.com/desktop2x/img/renderTimingPixel.png" style="width: 1px; height: 1px;" onload="(__markFirstCommentVisible || function(){})();">
              </div><button class="_1nGapmdexvR0BuOkfAi6wa t1_i964kf3 _1zN1-lYh2LfbYOMAho_O8g _2Gzh48SaLz7dQBCULfOC6V"><i class="icon icon-expand _1tnrhhM9S7dYjApTfvd14l"></i></button><div class="_2mHuuvyV9doV3zwbZPtIPG ZvAy-PJfJmB8pzQxpz1sS"><div id="AvatarUserInfoTooltip--t1_i964kf3"><a class="_3GfQMgsm3HGd3838lwqCST" data-testid="comment_author_icon" href="/user/JohnDude26/"><div class="_2p14AQvJBvTrEEa4csiW9v _1TENjLYSaj4L4uJMZa3DRe"><div class="_1cyAeeYDGrx7MPL_jRwKZ _13ScjOmi6dGdJw0JAonQEr  "><div class="_2_QqG5dG916znjlVV8ZCbw"></div><div class="_1XJXnCAngvZLEeLpB3oa4L"><img alt="User avatar" class="ScrrUjzznpAqm92uwgnvO" src="https://styles.redditmedia.com/t5_5nm6m/styles/profileIcon_snoo6dfbc823-0990-46ca-a356-e65bc689c871-headshot-f.png?width=256&amp;height=256&amp;crop=256:256,smart&amp;s=9caa07dc9cfc141789c6f900de3487ed8faaab7f"></div></div></div></a></div></div><div class="_3tw__eCCe7j-epNCKGXUKk"><span class="_1RIl585IYPW6cmNXwgRz0J">level 1</span><div class="-Xcv3XBXmgiY2X5RqaPbO _1S45SPAIb30fsXtEcKPSdt _3LqBzV8aCO9tge99jHiUGy " data-testid="post-comment-header"><span class="_1a_HxF03jCyxnx706hQmJR"><div class="_3QEK34iVL1BjyHAVleVVNQ"><div class="_2mHuuvyV9doV3zwbZPtIPG"><div id="UserInfoTooltip--t1_i964kf3"><a class="wM6scouPXXsFDSZmZPHRo DjcdNGtVXPcxG0yiFXIoZ _23wugcdiaj44hdfugIAlnX " data-testid="comment_author_link" href="/user/JohnDude26/">JohnDude26</a></div></div></div><span class="_2ETuFsVzMBxiHia6HfJCTQ _8b8fUdBRxCYj9MkNpFvvv"> · </span><a class="_3yx4Dn0W3Yunucf5sVJeFU" data-testid="comment_timestamp" href="https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/usqr2n/comment/i964kf3/?utm_source=reddit&amp;utm_medium=web2x&amp;context=3" id="CommentTopMeta--Created--t1_i964kf3" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">11 hr. ago</a><div class="_3XoW0oYd5806XiOr24gGdb"><span class="_2OYwDdghtXEuTF67C95YLY" id=""><span id="CommentAwardBadges--t1_i964kf3-gid_2"><img alt="Gold" class="n08B7PrU01wzgZYIh-s7N " id="awardItem__t1_i964kf3-gid_2" src="https://www.redditstatic.com/gold/awards/icon/gold_32.png"></span><span></span></span><span class="_2OYwDdghtXEuTF67C95YLY" id=""><span id="CommentAwardBadges--t1_i964kf3-award_f44611f1-b89e-46dc-97fe-892280b13b82"><img alt="Helpful" class="n08B7PrU01wzgZYIh-s7N " id="awardItem__t1_i964kf3-award_f44611f1-b89e-46dc-97fe-892280b13b82" src="https://preview.redd.it/award_images/t5_22cerq/klvxk1wggfd41_Helpful.png?width=32&amp;height=32&amp;auto=webp&amp;s=a6882eb3f380e8e88009789f4d0072e17b8c59f1"></span><span>4</span></span><span class="_2OYwDdghtXEuTF67C95YLY" id=""><span id="CommentAwardBadges--t1_i964kf3-award_5f123e3d-4f48-42f4-9c11-e98b566d5897"><img alt="Wholesome" class="n08B7PrU01wzgZYIh-s7N " id="awardItem__t1_i964kf3-award_5f123e3d-4f48-42f4-9c11-e98b566d5897" src="https://preview.redd.it/award_images/t5_22cerq/5izbv4fn0md41_Wholesome.png?width=32&amp;height=32&amp;auto=webp&amp;s=d11484a208d68a318bf9d4fcf371171a1cb6a7ef"></span><span>4</span></span><span class="_2OYwDdghtXEuTF67C95YLY" id=""><span id="CommentAwardBadges--t1_i964kf3-gid_1"><img alt="Silver" class="n08B7PrU01wzgZYIh-s7N " id="awardItem__t1_i964kf3-gid_1" src="https://www.redditstatic.com/gold/awards/icon/silver_32.png"></span><span>3</span></span><button data-click-id="awards" id="CommentAwardBadges--t1_i964kf3-view-all" class="_1tAFPduILh7Zse0gkxT4vj">&amp; 2 More</button></div></span></div><div data-testid="comment" class="_3cjCphgls6DH-irkVaA0GM "><div style="color:#1A1A1B" class="_292iotee39Lmt0MkQZ2hPV RichTextJSON-root"><p class="_1qeIAgB0cPwnLhDF9XSiJM">My man this is reddit.</p></div></div><div class="_3KgrO85L1p9wQbgwG27q4y"><div class="_1E9mcoVn4MYnuBQSVDt1gC _2oM1YqCxIwkvwyeZamWwhW _1ewTEGuogtFmDvDII2T2Yy" id="vote-arrows-t1_i964kf3"><button aria-label="upvote" aria-pressed="false" class="voteButton _2m5vzALl8kQdr9kwIFUo5t " data-click-id="upvote"><span class="_2q7IQ0BUOWeEZoeAxN555e _3SUsITjKNQ7Tp0Wi2jGxIM _22nWXKAY6OzAfK5GcUqWV2 qW0l8Af61EP35WIG6vnGk _3edNsMs0PNfyQYofMNVhsG"><i class="icon icon-upvote _2Jxk822qXs4DaXwsN7yyHA"></i></span></button><div class="_1rZYMD_4xY3gRcSS3p8ODO _25IkBM0rRUqWX5ZojEMAFQ _3ChHiOyYyUkpZ_Nm3ZyM2M" style="color:#1A1A1B">23.5k</div><button aria-label="downvote" aria-pressed="false" class="voteButton _2m5vzALl8kQdr9kwIFUo5t" data-click-id="downvote"><span class="_1iKd82bq_nqObFvSH1iC_Q Q0BxYHtCOJ_rNSPJMU2Y7 _2fe-KdD2OM0ciaiux-G1EL _3yQIOwaIuF6gn8db96Gu7y"><i class="icon icon-downvote ZyxIIl4FP5gHGrJDzNpUC"></i></span></button></div><div class="XZK-LTFT5CgGo9MvPQQsy _1LXnp2ufrzN6ioaTLTjGQ1 _2t8wLytikHzPCUnvXdS_wu _3rHRwVOKmBBlBOQ4kIW_vq _2_lhaFUJdP8q0o2L9MN2TN"><button class="_374Hkkigy4E4srsI2WktEd"><i class="icon icon-comment _1g4YvNNIFoV_5_EhsVfyRy"></i>Reply</button><div id="t1_i964kf3-comment-share-menu"><button class="_374Hkkigy4E4srsI2WktEd">Share</button></div><button class="_374Hkkigy4E4srsI2WktEd _2hr3tRWszeMRQ0u_Whs7t8 _14hLFU5cIJCyxH9DSgsCov">Report</button><button class="_374Hkkigy4E4srsI2WktEd _2hr3tRWszeMRQ0u_Whs7t8 _14hLFU5cIJCyxH9DSgsCov">Save</button><button class="_374Hkkigy4E4srsI2WktEd _2hr3tRWszeMRQ0u_Whs7t8 _14hLFU5cIJCyxH9DSgsCov">Follow</button><div class="hrV8gUgmt0V7wM2wgZ81l _1YnPvd-E5MbmcM3PvRRcX _14hLFU5cIJCyxH9DSgsCov"><button aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" aria-label="more options" id="t1_i964kf3-overflow-menu" class="_2pFdCpgBihIaYh9DSMWBIu _1VR6DV38j4rMT5OMeU4gJZ uMPgOFYlCc5uvpa2Lbteu"><i class="_38GxRFSqSC-Z2VLi5Xzkjy icon icon-overflow_horizontal"></i></button></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Update the question with relevant Html and also your expected output from html.

Comment: @KunduK Added the website and some details

Comment: The web url is not responding in my region. text based html would have been great for parent and child element. I can access upto `https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/`

Comment: @KunduK I added the HTML for the comment to the original post. Hopefully this is better

Comment: Xpathing from an element requires a . so child = parent.find_element(By.XPATH, './div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/span')

Answer (score 0):

Try it, I hope it will help you:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

parent = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[6]/div/div/div/div[1]")))

child = parent.find_element(By.XPATH,"/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/span")
```

Comment: I get a Timeout error when I run that